# Is waterfall a place or a fall of water?

Tags: meaning, word-usage, dictionaries

The Cambridge Dictionary defines 'waterfall' in this way: water, especially from a river or stream, dropping from a higher to a lower point, sometimes from a great height.

However, the Collins Dictionary defines 'waterfall' as a place where water flows over the edge of a steep, high cliff in hills or mountains, and falls into a pool below.

Also, the Wikipedia sources say that a waterfall is a place where water flows over a vertical drop or a series of steep drops in the course of a stream or river.

Comment: "Waterfall" refers to a location where there it falling water.  I think you are misinterpreting the Cambridge definition.

Comment: What exactly is the distinction you're trying to draw? Between the location where water drops from a height versus the water itself dropping from that height?

Comment: I have seen some dried up places where water fell.

Comment: Isn't it obviously both? Water in the shape of a waterfall but without the geography around it, is that a waterfall? A precipice that used to have water going over it but has dried up, is that a waterfall?

Comment: Indoor waterfalls (or artificial waterfalls) have nothing to do with geography. If one of them is built in a restaurant, for example, what makes it a waterfall is the water falling down—not the fact that it's at a particular location or that it involves a geographical element.

Comment: Could you please look instead at what constitutes a road junction?

Everyone knows it means a joining of two or more roads and everyone knows it means a place where two or more roads join and so what?

There are as many similar examples as there are stars in the sky and almost always both will be true and neither will be obviously preferable, except from the context.

Comment: to troll ever so slightly but, not only is it a place or a fall of water but it is also a metaphor for a flow of things dropping into a place well beyond water.  We're not quite getting a waterfall of answers to this question but some questions might.

Comment: Folks please compare the ODOL and Cambridge entries for "What exactly is the distinction you're trying to draw?" and other Qs.

Comment: You could #CollinsDictionary -- Good Luck. As for WP, it's after all, a wiki.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's water first, the place comes next.

**[waterfall](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/us/waterfall)** (ODOL)

> noun
>   A cascade of water falling from a height, formed when a river or stream flows over a precipice or steep incline.

---

[Edit]

Curiously, [TFD](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/waterfall) provides this definition

> *n* (Physical Geography) a cascade of falling water where there is a vertical or almost vertical step in a river

citing

> waterfall. (n.d.) Collins English Dictionary – Complete and Unabridged, 12th Edition 2014. (1991, 1994, 1998, 2000, 2003, 2006, 2007, 2009, 2011, 2014).

(Retrieved June 14 2018)

Note the source and the date.